# Pytest-parallel executing test case twice

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-parallel

For parallel execution i am using pytest-parallel, it works but each test cases is executing twice

```
def test_2():
    assert 2==2

def test_3():
    assert 1 == 1
```

command used

```
pytest -v -s test_file.py --workers auto
```

What auto will do like trigger as many workers as tests (each worker per test case)

and the result

```
collected 2 items
pytest-parallel: 8 workers (processes), 1 test per worker (thread)

testing_parallel.py::test_2 PASSED
testing_parallel.py::test_2 PASSED
testing_parallel.py::test_3 PASSED
testing_parallel.py::test_3 PASSED
```

tried with --workers 2

```
collected 2 items
pytest-parallel: 2 workers (processes), 1 test per worker (thread)

testing_parallel.py::test_2
testing_parallel.py::test_3 PASSED
testing_parallel.py::test_2 PASSEDPASSED
testing_parallel.py::test_3 PASSED
```

Here only test cases are there but execution is twice for each test case

Comment: Try with `--workers 2`?

Comment: tried that too, didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Actually your tests are being executing only once.

Problem is that the logging is shown results twice.

If you try to put a print inside of your code you will see they will only appear once at the console.

```
def test_2():
    print("Im running test 2")
    assert 2==2

def test_3():
    print("Im running test 3")
    assert 1 == 1
```